# SQL Server 2008 clr integration

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, clr

I am developing a project,create a CLR Integration.When loading the dll file to SQL Server,it print error.

Load command:`CREATE ASSEMBLY WcfApp from 'G:\WcfAppTest.dll'`.

The error is :Can not find `system.runtime.serialization`,

`WcfAppTest.dll` is also a WCF client,I want to send some message to `WCF Server` in `PROCEDURE`.

Can you give me a handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of [supported assembblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279(v=sql.100).aspx) is documented:

```
CustomMarshalers
Microsoft.VisualBasic
Microsoft.VisualC
mscorlib
System
System.Configuration
System.Data
System.Data.OracleClient
System.Data.SqlXml
System.Deployment
System.Security
System.Transactions
System.Web.Services
System.Xml
System.Core.dll
System.Xml.Linq.dll
```

WCF based assemblies are [not supported](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/922672/en-us):

> An untested .NET Framework assembly may exit its host process when a critical condition such as low-memory condition occurs. You can use the assembly in the SQL Server CLR-hosted environment at your own risk. However, Microsoft SQL Server Customer Support Services (CSS) will not help you to use and troubleshoot issues that are associated with an unsupported .NET Framework assembly.

I recommend you do your WCF calls from outside SQL, in your application. There are many reasons why this is a much better solution than using SQLCRL.